# How can I read a comma delimited text file in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I can get it to read the text file until it becomes a comma delimited text file.

I would like to read the two variables on each line and test each one with a If statement for another condition. Problem is I can't read the variables properly. Tried many things but here is what I will post. Timeouts are to see what's happening:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (TestText.txt) do (
timeout /t 1
echo %%a is the present variabe
timeout /t 2
if %%a=="One","1" echo Match for "One","1"
timeout /t 3
if %%a=="One""1" echo Match for "One","1"
timeout /t 4
if %%a=="One" echo Match for "One"
timeout /t 5
if %%a=="1" echo Match for "1"
timeout /t 6
)
```

**TestText.txt**

```
"One","1"
"Two","2"
"Three","3"
"Four","4"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
"One","1" is the present variabe
```

Comment: Unless you say otherwise, I will assume you mean the Windows command line and not a variant of DOS. There *is* a difference.

Comment: @Sms: If you want to edit your question or post a comment, and you already lost your cookie, try registering your account.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your condition is that you have to escape the comma (`,`). On the command prompt, this is done with a caret (`^`).

This works:

```
for /f %%a in (TestText.txt) do (
    if %%a=="One"^,"1" echo Match for "One","1"
)
```

However, since you are using CSV, you might want to split each line by the commas. This is done with the `tokens=1-n delims=,` option, where `n` is the number of values per line.

The separate values will be stored in `%%a`, `%%b`, etc.:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%a in (TestText.txt) do (
    if %%a=="One" echo Match for "One"
    if %%b=="1"   echo Match for "1"
)
```

#### Further information

- [Batch files - Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)
- [NT's FOR /F command: tokens and delims](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php)

Comment: Note that specifying `tokens=1*` will actually store every token after the first one in `%%b`. If the input line were `"One","1","a"` then `%%a` would get `"One"` and `%%b` would get `"1","a"`. Arguably, the more correct way is `tokens=1,2`, which will ignore any tokens after the second one. Of course, the choice of which to use depends on the situation.

Comment: Oh, and good answer. I'm too slow :P